# Chrome enable WebGL command line

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, chromium, webgl

I'm trying to open a remote application that needs WebGL, but some of the users manually disable it for other reasons.
I tried to activate by command line, but it doesn't work, I tried several combinations, I know Chromium must be closed to accept the settings.

The command on the server looked like this:

```
chrome --enable-gpu -–use-gl=desktop --app="http://localhost:8000"
```

I read this documentation about Switches:
[Run Chromium with flags](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags)

In it I found a very detailed list:
[List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Even so Chromium or Google Chrome always starts disabled if the user has manually disabled it:
[image]

What's really weird is that if hardware acceleration is enabled and I try to start with the command line to "enable" WebGL is also disabled.

This leads me to believe that I am not using switches correctly.

Comment: The URL to the detailed list does not work.

Comment: I'm sorry. Now it's fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests I managed to solve, the Switch was missing `--in-process-gpu`

**Result:**

```
start chrome --app="http://localhost:8000" --gpu --gpu-launcher --in-process-gpu --ignore-gpu-blacklist --ignore-gpu-blocklist
```